# How to ignore css class

Tags: jquery, css

Can a css value be ignored ?

I have two divs :

```
<div id="div1" class="class1 class2">
</div>

<div id="div2" class="class1">
</div>
```

Can the css class be applied to just divs which are styled with class1 and if they contain class2 then its ignored ? So in above divs just div2 is styled with class1 because div1 is also styled with class2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Write like this:

```
.class1{
  background:red;
}
.class1.class2{
  background:none;
}
```

Comment: This is the way to go - no jquery necessary.

Comment: @chipcullen That's why i prefer CSS first then JS.

Comment: @bretterer No, because OP does not know how to solve this and he may accept jquery solutions, too. But when there's a cross-browser compatible way doing this with css only then this solution is preferrable. At least it's my pov. And this here is very basic css knowledge.

Comment: If you have a lot of rules for `.class1`, overriding them all in `.class1 .class2` into default values would be a tedious task, especially if some values are inherited from parent but changed by `.class1`.

Comment: @Abody97 I agree, but using `:not` selector is not really addressing the OP's question as well. Here you must ensure to not have some rules in some other `class1` selector anywhere that will then applied to the tag again. If he wants to suppress all rules of `class1` selectors when some other is present then he have to remove its class from the tag.

Comment: `Can the css class be applied to just divs which are styled with class1 and if they contain class2 then its ignored ?` I agree that they should be removed altogether in that case, but, I really think that's what the OP meant.

Answer (score 14):

You can use the `:not` selector. Here's an example:

CSS

```
.red:not(.yellow) {
    color: red;
}
.yellow {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class = "red yellow">
   Glee's awesome!
</div>
<div class = "red">
   Glee's awesome!
</div>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/djMx4/)**.

I hope that helped!

Comment: +1 Seems to be a valid solution depending what the OP is really trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `:not` selector:

```
$('.class1:not(.class2)')
```

Answer (score 1):

YESSSS,

use !important after the css property

for example `height:30px !important`

if your class1 have `height:30px`
and class2 `height:40px` then user !important in class2 height

Comment: it is possible to use !important and it is also working, but you should avoid this if possible and try to search for a better solution. keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would handle this with jquery ( since its how you tagged it and if you only ever want the div with just class class1) is to do a check such as

```
if($('div').class() == 'class1') {


}
```

This will select only the div where class equals `class1` and not the one with class of `class1 class2`

Answer (score 0):

Great answers here and I just want to add here a little bit:
You've to decide here between selectors that seem to do the same but are a little different:

- "Override `class1` styles when `class2` is present." or "I want special styles when both classes are present."
- "Apply special styles when `class1` is present and `class2` is not."
- "I really want to suppress all rules of `class1` selectors when `class2` is present."

You've to decide what exactly your requirements are. There is a difference between these sentences.

In the first case go with CSS selectors like @sandeep posted, because these selectors work like this. The `.class1.class2` selector is more specific than `.class1` selector and it is choosen over it when both classes are present. So you can set there the rules you want to be applied only if both classes are present. Collidating rules in the more specific selector have higher priority than in then other and are able to override it.

In the second case go with the `:not` selectors. These make it possible to apply certain styles only when a class is present and some other is not.

For the third case:
Your question is pointing at ignoring a css class. This is not possible. You can override its rules in a more specific selector or put its rules in a selector not matching certain tags anymore. But you cannot ignore it as long as its there. Therefore you've to remove the `class1` from the class attribute of the tag. You can achieve this with jQuery though.

```
 $(".class2").removeClass("class1");
```